# Plotting multiple pandas DataFrames in one *3D* scatterplotplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot two dataframes in one 3D scatterplot.

This is the code I have for one dataframe:

```
import seaborn as sns
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

...

sns.set(style = "darkgrid")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
x = df['xitem']
y = df['yitem']
z = df['zitem']

ax.set_xlabel("X Label")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Label")
ax.set_zlabel("Z Label")

ax.scatter(x, y, z)

plt.show()
```

I can't figure out how to adjust this so I have two different dataframes plotted on the same plot but with different colors. How can I do this?

Edit: I'm looking for how to use two dataframes for a 3D plot specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have two DataFrame called `df1` and `df2`, both containing columns `'xitem', 'yitem', 'zitem'`, you can plot them in this way:

```py
for curr_df, c in zip((df1, df2), ('b', 'r')):
    ax.scatter(*curr_df[['xitem', 'yitem', 'zitem']].values.T, color=c)
```

Here a complete example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style = "darkgrid")

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.random((100, 3)) + np.array([1, 1, 1]),
    columns=['xitem', 'yitem', 'zitem'],
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.random((100, 3)),
    columns=['xitem', 'yitem', 'zitem'],
)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

for curr_df, c in zip((df1, df2), ('b', 'r')):
    ax.scatter(*curr_df[['xitem', 'yitem', 'zitem']].values.T, color=c)

ax.set_xlabel("X Label")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Label")
ax.set_zlabel("Z Label")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: [Since heavily importing into the global namespace may result in unexpected behavior, the use of pylab is strongly discouraged. Use matplotlib.pyplot instead.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html?highlight=pylab#module-pylab)

Comment: @Mr. T thanks, I didn't know that. I've updated the answer